# How to reuse same where-clause on different entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In my app a logged in admin-user can see "partners" based on some permissions:

```
public async Task<IList<Partner>> GetPartners(IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin)
{
    bool all = permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "All");
    bool sameArea = permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "SameArea");

    var p = _dbContext.Partners.Where(x => all || (sameArea && x.AreaId == Admin.AreaId));

    return await p.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```

Each partner is associated to different programs. The admin can see all programs, but when accessing it still only the partners based on the permissions. Like:

```
public async Task<IList<ProgramPartner>> GetProgramPartners(IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin, Guid programId)
{
    bool all = permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "All");
    bool sameArea = permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "SameArea");

    var p = _dbContext.ProgramPartners.Where(x => x.ProgramId == programId && 
        (all || (sameArea && x.Partner.AreaId == Admin.AreaId))
    );

    return await p.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync()
}
```

These are very basic examples. The permission handling is much more complicated, so I'd like to reuse the Where-clause that handles it.

I've tried to make a method that returns true/false, but EF gives me an error, that the query couldn't be translated:

```
public bool FilterPartners(Partner partner, IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin)
{
    bool all = permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "All");
    bool ownArea = permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "OwnArea");

    return all || (ownArea && partner.AreaId == admin.AreaId);
}

public async Task<IList<Partner>> GetPartners(IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin)
{
    var p = _dbContext.Partners.Where(x => FilterPartners(x, permissions, admin));

    return await p.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<IList<ProgramPartner>> GetProgramPartners(IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin, Guid programId)
{
    var p = _dbContext.Partners.Where(x => x.ProgramId == programId).Where(x => FilterPartners(x.Partner, permissions, admin));

    return await p.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```

I've also tried passing an IQueryable to a method and back and also looked at Expressions functions, but that didn't work at all.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Where are `permissions` coming from? Is it stored in memory, or is it also coming off the database?

Comment: Permissions are stored in database but retrieved to memory and passed to methods as needed.

Comment: If you can show how those permissions are retrieved, it might be possible to do it as a join, using `IQueryable<Permission>`

Comment: That's fairly straightforward. I have a table with permissions(int Id, string Key, string Value). Each admin has an AdminRole and each role has a linked set of permissions from the permissions table: AdminRolePermissions(permissionId, adminRoleId).

Comment: Without third party library like LINQKit you can't do that. EF will not translate compiled method body. If you OK, I can show example.

Answer (score 1):

It's long shot, but have you tried something among these lines:

```
IQueryable<T> FilterPartners<T>(
    IQueryable<T> query,
    Func<T, Partner> getPartner,
    IList<Permission> permissions,
    Admin admin)
{
    return query.Where(item =>
        permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "All")
        || (permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "OwnArea") 
            && getPartner(item).AreaId == admin.AreaId));
}

async Task<IList<Partner>> GetPartners(IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin)
{
    var p = _dbContext.Partners.Where(x => FilterPartners(x, permissions, admin));

    return await p.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}

async Task<IList<ProgramPartner>> GetProgramPartners(
    IList<Permission> permissions, 
    Admin admin, 
    Guid programId)
{
    IQueryable<ProgramPartner> dbQuery = null; //_dbContext.Partners
    dbQuery = dbQuery
        .Where(x => x.ProgramId == programId);

    dbQuery = FilterPartners(dbQuery, x => x.Partner, permissions, admin);

    return await p.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: making it an extension method might be neater `this IQueryable<T> query` then you can do `dbQuery = dbQuery.FilterPartners(x =>...` Also why `.ToListAsync()` it seems unnecessarily inefficient? Instead just pass around `IQueryable` and let the finla translation do all the joins.

Comment: @Michal That could maybe work, but it gives me a (missing cast?) from System.Linq.IQueryable<T> to System.Linq.IQueryable<Models.ProgramPartner>.

Comment: @Charlieface could you post an example?

Comment: @Mads sounds like you are returning collection of `ProgramPartners` instead of collection of type T in `FilterPartners` method

Answer (score 0):

An `IQueryable` is not materialized until `ToListAsync` is called, and all functions applied to it must be translatable, so you can't just call any function you like inside its lambdas.

You need the filter function to receive and return an `IQueryable`. Then the function rewrites the query contained in that and returns a new one with the filter added.

You can do this as an extension function to make it easier to read.

```cs
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    (bool all, bool ownArea) CalculatePermissions(IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin)
    {
        bool all = permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "All");
        bool ownArea = permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "OwnArea");
        return (all, ownArea);
    }

    public IQueryable<Partner> FilterPartners(this IQueryable<Partner> source,
        IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin)
    {
        (var all, var ownArea) = CalculatePermissions(permissions, admin);
        return source.Where(p => all || (ownArea && p.AreaId == admin.AreaId));
    }

    public IQueryable<ProgramPartner> FilterProgramPartners(this IQueryable<ProgramPartner> source,
        IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin, Guid programId)
    {
        (var all, var ownArea) = CalculatePermissions(permissions, admin);
        return source.Where(pp =>
            all ||
            (
               ownArea &&
               pp.Partner.Any(p => p.AreaId == admin.AreaId))
            );
    }
}
```

```cs
public async Task<IList<Partner>> GetPartners(IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin)
{
    var p = _dbContext.Partners.FilterPartners(permissions, admin);
    return await p.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<IList<ProgramPartner>> GetProgramPartners(IList<Permission> permissions, Admin admin, Guid programId)
{
    var p = _dbContext.ProgramPartners
        .Where(p => p.ProgramId == programId)
        .FilterProgramPartners(permissions, admin);

    return await p.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
}
```

Note that depending on your setup, it may be possible to pass through `permissions` as `IQueryable<Permission>` (ie you don't store the permission list in memory), and then your extension function should look like this

```
public IQueryable<Partner> FilterPartners(this IQueryable<Partner> partnerSource,
    IQueryable<Permission> permissions, Admin admin)
{
    return partnerSource.Where(p =>
        permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "All")
        || (
           permissions.Any(x => x.Key == "SeePartners" && x.Value == "OwnArea") &&
           p.AreaId == admin.AreaId
          )
        );
}
```

In other words, you mustn't use an `IQueryable` by itself, only as part of another query, so that you just do a single `.ToListAsync` as the end which materializes it from the database.

Comment: thanks, really appreciate it. The thing is, that your function only takes half of the logic; finding the permissions. What I'd really like was to also have the validation against the permission-booleans in the function by passing the IQueryable<Partner> entity, that's available no matter if I query for Partners or ProgramPartners. But maybe it isn't possible?

Comment: No I don't think it is, because one of them needs `Expression<Func<Partner, bool>>` and the other `Expression<Func<ProgramPartner, bool>>`. You might be able to factor out the comparison on `admin.AreaId` but you need the overall lambda for `ProgramPartner`.